# Cannot Load Blob using XmlHttpRequest in IE10

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest, blob

I tried to load an image from an image path (http path) within the same domain,
the methods I've been using is by XmlHttpRequest and it worked properly on Chrome and then I displayed the image inside the img tag in HTML5,

When I tried to load it in IE10, it just won't work, the status and readyState are normal,
but the image won't load, and when I checked the XmlHttpRequest property 'response', it returned blob object on Chrome, but it returned undefined on IE10,

**NOTE** **: I used onload event on Chrome, but on IE I used onreadystatechanged**

here is the code I'm using:

```
           var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
           xhr.open("GET", "http://pathtomyimage/example.jpg", true);
           xhr.responseType = "blob";
           xhr.onreadystatechange = function (e) {
               if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200) {
                   alert(xhr.response+" in IE");
                   var i;
                   i= document.getElementById("bg");
                   i.src = URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response);
               }
           };
           xhr.onload = function (e) {
               if (this.status == 200) {
                   var myBlob = this.response;
                   alert(myBlob+" inChrome");
                   var i;
                   i= document.getElementById("bg");
                   i.src = URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
               }
           };
           xhr.onerror = function (e) {
               alert(e+"  error");
           };
           xhr.send();
```

inside the onreadystatechange, the alert returned undefined on IE10, and the alert inside the onload is returning blob-object on Chrome,
So how can I display the image on IE10 like I did on Chrome?

Comment: And why are you making an Ajax request to fetch an image and not just linking to the image to begin with?

Comment: because I need to store it in IndexedDB or in some kind of storage, and the path is dynamically changed because of synchronization process I have, in short, I need the image to be fetched as a Blob

Comment: the image displaying is just for me to test whether the blob that was fetched is actually exist and correct

Comment: Just make a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HxYJs/) for your code but change the url. It worked. Are you using IE10 standart document mode?

Comment: @VitorCanova when you said standard document mode, I immediately checked my IE and finally see that it is in its compatibility view, that's why the response is undefined, it's working fine now, thanks!

Comment: @EldonLesley I made a real answer so you can accept. Thank's

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code in [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HxYJs/) but changed the url and it worked.

```
xhr.open("GET", "http://fiddle.jshell.net/js/lib/dummy.js", true)
```

Probably you are not using IE in their standard mode.

Press F12 and take a look at those things:

`Browser Mode: IE10`

`Document Mode: Standards`